# "sudo" causes "Server returned error NXDOMAIN"

Tags: sudo

Each time I "sudo" from my log in user I am getting this error. Any command preceded by "sudo" causes this. I have checked many replies on this forum about dealing with this message but it only seems to happen when "sudo" [sudo su - or sudo "ls -al" etc] is used. So it appears to be very specific to this action. I understand that it's quite innocuous but does anyone know why this is happening ?

OS: ubuntu 20.10 (Groovy Gorilla)
System: Raspberry Pi 4, 4Gb
Installed software: Only the base operating system has been installed together with ubuntu-desktop, xrdp and nettools. No additional software.
The syslog message is:
`Jan  8 10:20:00 pi011 systemd-resolved[1625]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP. Jan  8 10:20:00 pi011 systemd-resolved[1625]: message repeated 3 times: [ Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.]`

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks
Greg

**New:**
I can nslookup any domain without a problem and telnet to any internet web server without any errors in the syslog. The only time the error appears in the syslog is when I use sudo although it may not be directly related to sudo; however it happens every time I use sudo.

**New:**
Thanks, its resolved now by adding the host name of the server to the hosts file.

Comment: That error has nothing to do with sudo.  See launchpad bugs 1727237,1805027,1804487.  Do you have any problems connecting to any domains?

Comment: @ubfan1. Not sure what you mean by connecting to any domains. I can nslookup any domain without a problem and telnet to any internet web server without any errors in the syslog. The only time the error appears in the syslog is when I use sudo although it may not be directly related to sudo; however it happens every time I use sudo.

Comment: Is your `hostname` in `/etc/hosts`? What's in `/etc/resolv.conf`, `/etc/nsswitch. conf`?

Comment: Please edit your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: @ubfan1: It  IS `sudo` reporting an error - `sudo` got a "Non Existent Domain", `NXDOMAIN` error from `systemd-resolvd` while trying to resolve `localhost`.